# Why is my unserialize returning empty?

Tags: php, session, serialization

This could be a duplicate, but i couldn't find any one that helped.

I'm trying to pass an array of all the data to another page, throught the post method of a form. It looks like this:

```
        <form method="post" action="../resource_load/export.php" target="_blank">
        <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="<?=$_GET['tipo']?>">
        <input type='hidden' name='excel_array' value='<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($_SESSION['excel_array']))?>'>
        <input  type='submit' class='submit' id='btnExport' value='Export to Excel' />
```

So here i serialize the $_SESSION data. and this is what it looks like:

```
    value="a:1:{s:12:"dpi_strategy";a:1:{s:5:"Plan1";a:1:{i:0;a:9:{i:0;s:3:"PCR";i:1;s:11:"Description";i:2;s:4:"Task";i:3;s:8:"Resource";i:4;s:13:"Baseline Plan";i:5;s:10:"Trend Date";i:6;s:4:"User";i:7;s:20:"Data Inicialização";i:8;s:6:"Status";}}}}
```

And here is where i unserialize:

```
    $Excel_array = htmlentities(unserialize($_POST['excel_array']));
```

Yet, it returns null. Why is that?

Comment: I don't get it. You serialize a session variable and the unserliaze it in another page/script? Just access the session variable in your other page

Comment: I want to turn it into $_POST data, so it won't be replaced when i open another tab

Comment: It won't be replaced. Just access the session data on your other page. Try it.

Comment: You're not decoding and you're doing it backwards: `unserialize(html_entity_decode($_POST['excel_array']));`

Comment: What i mean is, if the user opens various tabs, only the most recent session will remain, and i'm currently exporting the Session information to excel, which is why i want to use $_POST instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this, use `htmlentities()` to encode and `html_entity_decode()` to decode with **raw** values.

Secondly, I don't believe it is a good idea to output the data of serialize and unserialize user submitted data. The reason being is code injection that is a major security issue.

Instead, use `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`.
Now because I see you have special chars in your array `Data Inicialização` you are indeed correct to convert those characters to another entity, but aslong if you have everything UTF-8 it will work.

```
<input type='hidden' name='excel_array' value='<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['excel_array']) ?>'>
```

And:

```
# ../resource_load/export.php 
var_dump(json_decode($_POST['excel_array']);
```

Comment: I'm turning it into $_POST information because i want to retain these informations even after i open another page and consequently, another session.

Comment: Sessions work by a cookie ID, you can close the browser and the data in a session will still be there. This holds true until the cookie is expired or removed by means of clean up tools. If you open it via a different browser, it would be handled as a new request and a new session will start still keeping the data from the other browser intact.

Comment: I believe i'm not explaining this correctly. I need to have various "Sessions" opened at the same time, because i'm exporting the Session data to excel. Since i cannot separate the sessions through tabs, i'm trying to use export $_POST data onto Excel instead.

Comment: @RazorFinger Answer adjusted accordingly, though I'd still think you need to implement it differently. You could always print a random id with the form, and set the `$_Session['id']['exceldata']` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $temp = array();
    $temp['aaa'] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    $temp['bbb'] = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb";
    $temp['ccc'] = "ccccccccccccccccccccccc";

    $arr = array();
    $arr['excel_array'] = $temp;


?>

 <form method="post" action="">
     <input type='hidden' name='excel_array' value='<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($arr['excel_array']))?>'>
    <input  type='submit' class='submit' id='btnExport' value='Export to Excel' />

</form>


<?php


if( isset($_POST['excel_array']) ) {
    echo "<pre>";
    $Excel_array = unserialize($_POST['excel_array']);
    print_r($Excel_array);
}


?>
```

remove htmlentities from unserialize because you will unserialize an array and htmlentities use strings